# Android PreferenceManager in staticmethod

Tags: android, android-preferences

If I try to write this method

```
public static void saveDefaultUser() {
        Editor pName = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())
                .edit();
        pName.putString("Name", name);
        pName.commit();
}
```

doesn't compile and I have to remove the ***static*** value, 
because clearly I cannot make a static reference to the non static method.

Is there is a way to adapt this for the use in static method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to pass in a `Context` to your method and use that instead of `getBaseContext()`.

```
public static void saveDefaultUser( Context cntxt ) {
    Editor pName = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntxt)
            .edit();
    pName.putString("Name", name);
    pName.commit();
}
```